# What presentation design pattern fits HTML5 development?

Tags: silverlight, design-patterns, html

There are various discussions about whether to use Flash, Silverlight or HTML5. When it comes to Silverlight, it has very different programming experience (more of a desktop model), and this makes it reasonable for Silverlight applications to use MVVP presentation pattern.

But when it comes to pure HTML5-based Web application, is there any well-known presentation design pattern that provides a good fit for them and is often chosen by developers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What is your criteria? Does it just need to be well-known? How do you define good fit? Is it only important that the pattern be socially acceptable among programmers, or are there other, more important characteristics you are considering? Are you looking for server-side or client-side patterns?

Comment: Robert,

Perhaps using "well-known" was not necessary: pattern is something of a common use, this is why it is called pattern (or anti-pattern). But what I am after is to find references to presentation patterns that HTML5 developers use for client-side code. I gave an example of Silverlight where MVVM is fairly popular. Another example could be Android client application development where MVC is often applied. So if we take a well-written and complex HTML5 code, what presentation patterns is it likely to use?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think this area is very well-developed, because there just aren’t that many complex client-side web apps. Generally you do most of your work on the server — HTML (plus CSS) *is* your presentation layer.

When you are working on the client, the main vague pattern is:

- HTML is your interface
- CSS adds custom styles to the HTML (beyond the default styles that the browser assigns to HTML tags)
- JavaScript adds custom behaviour to the HTML by assigning functions to the available events on HTML tags, via the DOM

I don’t have any Flash or Silverlight experience, hence the vagueness of my answer.

It might be worth reading up a bit on [Cappucino](http://cappuccino.org/), which is a big framework for building complex UIs in HTML.